# UITableView reload data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

When I reload the UITableView some of its cell does not display but when I touch the screen they appears automatically.? Here is the UITableViewCellForRow code. I am reloading the table using code [tblBuddyMesssageList reloadData];

```
 if (tableView.tag == UITableViewTagBuddyMessageList)
 {
    Message  *buddyMsg = self.arrBuddyMessages[indexPath.row];

    if ([buddyMsg.senderName isEqualToString:applicationDelegate.userInfo.userName] && [buddyMsg.receiverName isEqualToString:self.selectedBuddy.userName])
    {
        MessageSendByMeCell *cell = [tblBuddyMessageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:messageSendByMeCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureMessageSendByMeCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
     else
    {
        MessageSendByBuddyCell *cell = [tblBuddyMessageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:messageSendByBuddyCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [self configureMessageSendByBuddyCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;        }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing it within a animation block with a duration of `0`?

Comment: when I do this  [tblBuddyMessageList reloadData]; Result is same.

Comment: where is that code positioned? is it executed on the main/ui thread?

Comment: can you please post tablviewCellForRowAtIndex methods code? and ensure you do the tableView reloadData on the main thread not from any thread other than it.

Comment: When application is running on simulator, on Xcode go to Debug>View Debugging>Capture View Hierarchy and check where are the frames of cell, that may give you the clue what is wrong. Also make sure you call reload method in main thread.